# Media Finder display Image on Front End

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I created a Model and Database and can upload an image using the Media Finder.

[image: media finder]

I set Media Finder field as `photo` in `fields.yamal`.

But after uploading, no image path is saved to the database in the photo column.

---

#### Database Tables

- id (integer)
- title (string)
- photo (string)

#### Twig

```
{% for product in builderListCatalog.records %}
    {{ product.title }}
    <img src="{{ product.photo }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

This successfully displays the Title but not the Photo path because it is empty in the database.

Comment: Can you reconstruct the path from image id plus file extension and image folder location..

Comment: @numbtongue I don't know where to begin on how to do that or how to get the image id. I don't know why the database won't save the path, even after October had a popup that said Media Finder required a database table to be usable.

Comment: There are some answers down here https://stackoverflow.com/q/47078147/3254405

Comment: @numbtongue I am using `public $attachOne` and have a DB table for it, but after uploading the image the path is not saved to the DB.

Comment: I am not fully understand but in the link it says you need to add a field in dB to record the image path https://stackoverflow.com/a/48582780/3254405

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove all the relation added to `that field from model`.

You are using `public $attachOn` **remove it that is the issue** now its treated like file attachment relation **not a finder image** so it will not store path of image in that `photo (string)` field in table

If you use `media finder` you just need to **add normal** `string (photo)` **field in table no need to add any relation in model** and it will just store `selected file path` in that field **for ex.** `/someimage.png`

> Now to show it in `front-end` you can use

```
<img src="{{ model.photo|media }}" />
```

> In component partial you can use

```
<img src="<?php echo 'https://october-plaza.com/storage/app/media/' . $model->photo ?>" />
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: It is working now. It looks like `$` doesn't work in twig. `{{ record.photo|media }}` works. Also I see `<?=` a lot but it doesn't work, I have to use `<?php`.

Comment: sorry my bad added `php code` in `twig` corrected ans `{{model.photo|media}}` thanks @MattMcManis

Comment: yes in FE `php will not work it has to be twig i guess`, but in `components` partials you can use `php` :)